# fetch selected item id(from db) in android ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

i have a listView that each row of that shows a text. each row fetched from database that has 2 fields:

1- id

2-text

now, in my list i have to show only my text not id. but i need when i click on a list row fetch each rows id that related to his text. in fact i fetch text,id pair from db and show the text and use id in on click event. but how i can do that? how i related id to each row?

Answer (score 0):

Set id as a tag to each view inside the listView and in onClick retrieve it

Comment: can you give me a simple example?

Comment: `View textView = findViewById(R.id.textview); textView.setText(text);textView.setTag(id);textView.setonclicklistener(listener);` in the listener's `onclick` method, do `long id = view.getTag();`

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter, set the tag of the TextView.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listView = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if( convertView == null){
        listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    else{
        listView = convertView;
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) listView.findview(R.id.textview);
    tv.setText("my-text");
    tv.setTag("my-id");

    return listView;
}
```

Retrieve the id :

```
// Main Activity 
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    String id = tv.getTag().toString();
}
```